# regex match all numbers between []

Tags: python, regex

really simple regex question I have string that may look like:

- [10]
- [6378363]30
- []393

I'd like it so it would match 10, 6378363 and nothing respectively.

I tried something like (\d+)[^]]
(match 1 or more numbers as we know the first character will always be [)
(up to ])

but this is just only matching numbers I am presuming I have the syntax for regex wrong as I am simply rubbish at regex! any help would be amazing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
\[(\d*)\]
```

The regex `(\d+)[^]]` would match digits until a `[` appears, so it won't capture digits between square brackets. `[` and `]` are special characters in regex, so they should be escaped with `\`.

```
>>> import re
>>> st = '[6378363]30'
>>> re.match('\[(\d*)\]', st).group(1)
'6378363'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this one:

```
import re

input = '[10] [6378363]30 []393'
print re.findall('\[(\d+)\]', input)
```

`\d+` means one or more digits. This will ensure to avoid `[]` as it does have zero digits inside it.

Comment: don't shadow `input`! :)

Comment: I think @zidsal wants to return an empty string for `'[]393'`

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks. Didn't know that. I am already habituated from not using `str`. Looks like I have to use this one too!

Comment: @IceArdor Lol. by `nothing respectively` I thought OP doesn't need to return anything else.

Comment: @SabujHassan I usually do `user_input` or etc. If you're getting info from the user, `from_stdin` sometimes works well too.

Comment: @IceArdor The "nothing" specification isn't clear... it could be an empty string, or it could mean no match.  I suppose that since the OP accepted the "\d*" version we know they wanted an empty string, but until that point it could have been either "\d*" or "\d+".

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is:

```
\[(\d*)\]
```